# Whay does the SQL Server Service account has the ""Impersonate a client after authentication" Right?

Tags: sql-server, spn

Our database is running on SQL Server 2008 hosted on a Windows 2008 Server. We have found that the security policy “**impersonate a Client after authentication**” is enabled for the SQL Server service account. Will removing “**impersonate a Client after authentication**” cause any issues? is this URA required for SQL to function correctly. The database hosted on this instance is a client-server application.

Comment: If you have installed optional components such as ASP.NET or IIS, you may need to assign the Impersonate a client after authentication user right to additional accounts that are required by those components.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mr. Haider. We have nothing else installed on the SQL server. However the application that connects to it is an .net based application that uses SPNs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documented [Windows Privileges and Rights](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx#Windows) for the database engine service account are:

> - Log on as a service (SeServiceLogonRight)
> - Replace a process-level token (SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege)
> - Bypass traverse checking (SeChangeNotifyPrivilege)
> - Adjust memory quotas for a process (SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege)
> - Permission to start SQL Writer
> - Permission to read the Event Log service
> - Permission to read the Remote Procedure Call service

The `SeImpersonatePrivilege` is only documented as required for the SSIS service.

That being said, I will say that the `SeImpersonatePrivilege` privilege is required for the database engine. Windows Authenticated client connections impersonate the client when accessing OS resources like SSPI linked servers and network shares (think db attach, backups etc).

Comment: I think this permission to impersonate is related to the Active Directory Service Account configuration.  Particularly if you are reaching across from one server to another with say,  Linked Servers, it will allow the service account to extend the permission that is granted to a specific user that isn't the same as what the service account might have.